# Node Transitioned from NEW to UNHEALTHY and Attempting to remove non-existent node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can someone fix this error?

```
2024-02-29 15:45:47,779 INFO rmnode.RMNodeImpl: LAPTOP-4F5S1RB8:64282 Node Transitioned from NEW to UNHEALTHY
2024-02-29 15:45:47,783 ERROR capacity.CapacityScheduler: Attempting to remove non-existent node LAPTOP-4F5S1RB8:64282
```

This error happens after I tried to using word count in `hadoop`.